# Присвоение переменной в Python количества записей в Access таблице

Tags: python, access, база-данных, sql

Подключился к Access таблице из Python

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb')
SqlAccess=conAcc.cursor();
```

Как присвоить переменной Python - CountOfRecords количество записей в таблице Клиенты базы данных Борей (D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb), получаемую sql-запросом

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM КЛИЕНТЫ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Может, fetchone?